# How To Handle conditional Routing or Component Navigation Without React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I need to navigate between components based on several conditions, and I do not want routes to be displayed in the browser, say localhost:3000/step1 or localhost:3000/step2. The whole application is guided so that a user have to answer all the steps to reach the final result.

ATM I have a main container which handles the component rendering based on the Redux store value.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class Home extends Component {
  renderComponent = screen => {
    switch (screen) {
     case 'SCREEN_A':
      return <ScreenA />;

     case 'SCREEN_B':
      return <ScreenB />;

     case 'SCREEN_C':
      return <ScreenC />;

     case 'SCREEN_D':
      return <ScreenD />;

     default:
      return <ScreenA />;
   }
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderComponent(this.props.currentScreen)}</div>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(storeData) {
  return {
    store: storeData,
    currentScreen: storeData.appState.currentScreen,
    userData: storeData.userData
 };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

The problem is I have to use dispatch to trigger navigation

```
navigateTo(screens[destination])
navigateBackward(currentScreen)
navigateForward(currentScreen)
```

in almost all components. I do have a predefined JSON for each component which contains the destination for each screen.

```
screens : {
 SCREEN_A:{
  id: 1,
  name: 'SCREEN_A',
  next: 'SCREEN_B',
  back: 'WELCOME_SCREEN',
  activeLoader: true,
 },
 SCREEN_B:{
  id: 2,
  name: 'SCREEN_B',
  next: 'SCREEN_C',
  back: 'WELCOME_SCREEN',
  activeLoader: true,
 },
 SCREEN_C:{
  id: 3,
  name: 'SCREEN_C',
  next: 'SCREEN_D',
  back: 'SCREEN_A',
  activeLoader: true,
 },
 SCREEN_D:{
  id: 4,
  name: 'SCREEN_D',
  next: 'SCREEN_E',
  back: 'SCREEN_D',
  activeLoader: true,
 },
}
```

And there are protected screens which makes things way more complicated. Is there a better way of doing this with redux? or should I create a middleware and intercept each state change and calculate the next screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change a few things:

1. Make your steps/screens dynamic. By putting them into an Array and using the index to determine the current step it removes a lot of code and will make it easier to add/move steps.
2. Store the steps/screens config in the redux store.
3. Optionally, you can pass the nextStep and previousStep to the StepComponent. e.g. `<StepComponent nextStep={nextStep} previousStep={previousStep} />`.

In your last step, you probably want to call a different action instead of nextStep.

Here's what my solution would look like:

```
// Home.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as types from '../../redux/Actor/Actor.types';

class Home extends Component {
  stepComponents = [
    ScreenA,
    ScreenB,
    ScreenC,
    ScreenD,
  ];

  render() {
    const { step, steps } = this.props;

    const StepComponent = this.stepComponents[step];

    return (
      <div>
        <StepComponent {...steps[step]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// store.jsx
export default {
  step : 0,
  steps: [
    {
      id          : 1,
      name        : 'SCREEN_A',
      activeLoader: true,
    },
    ....
  ],
};

// actions.jsx
export const nextStep = () => ({ type: 'NEXT_STEP' });
export const previousStep = () => ({ type: 'PREVIOUS_STEP' });

// reducers.jsx
export const nextStep = state => ({ ...state, step: state.step + 1 });
export const previousStep = state => ({ ...state, step: state.step - 1 });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, Sorry took some time to actually try this solution. It works especially the dynamic component rendering part. Is it possible to build a navigation system that watches the store and decides what should be the next step. example: I am doing an Api call and setting getData.isFetching = true, then getData.status = 200, then oh you got some data from getData so navigate to screenD. is this possible with reselect or any other approach ?

Comment: Sure, you could use an extra library like redux-sagas/redux-thunk or you could make the call in the component and handle the response from there. You would need to add a new action like `GOTO_STEP` with an `index` parameter and call this action after the response.

Comment: Great thanks, I am using thunks for async but I have to manually mention which screen it should go next. Let’s say the index should be passed after each api call and based on the output I have to navigate to index {n}. Where n should be calculated based on the current state

Comment: Yes, that's also possible. In this case, that logic should live in a reducer. If you dispatch a `RESPONSE_SUCCESS` action and pass the response, you should be able to calculate the next step using the current state and response data.

Comment: Oh, I was doing the same in another actionCreator. So I did if(response.message) dispatch(navigateTo(currentId)), so I use current ID to compute the next destination and dispatch another action

Comment: Sounds like you've found the solution, nice!